# Dynamically change localStorage content when item remove

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, local-storage

I want to dynamically change content , by following code.

`localStorage.removeItem("some key");`

but current page  is still show removed Item unless I reload page.
I want to do dynamically change this page's content when I remove localStorage item without
reload page.
Do you have any Idea?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to manually remove the DOM element from the page with javascript.  You would have to show the relevant HTML and describe which element you want to remove for anyone to offer advice on what javascript would remove the item from the page.

Comment: What do you mean under "page is still show removed Item"? `localStorage` is updated correctly.

Comment: There is no magical binding between `localStorage` and elements. You'll have to remove the element manually as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pimvdb said there is no magical binding between localStorage and elements:

You should implement your code in this way:

```
 $("button").click(function () {
     localStorage.removeItem("yourKey"); 
     $("#yourID").remove();  // it removes your DOM element
 });
```